# Automated image/css sprite generation from website DOM

Tags: css, web-services, sprite

I know there are plenty of online tools which let's you upload your images there and it generates the appropriate CSS/sprite(s) to be used with them on your page.

Is there any such website/tool which would take a website URL and parse from its DOM the images/css and calculate the sprites/css to be used specifically with that DOM, so you could just copy & replace your own CSS with the one provided by the tool?

I know the complexity of such calculations, but it certainly sounds like something that can be done, so my question is, is there something ready and available already?

Comment: I'd be surprised if there is. I'd be doubly surprised if it were free like the current sprite generators are.

Comment: @John Conde For static pages (without JS), it certainly doesn't sound like an impossibility. Even for dynamic elements, with a little user input, I'm sure you could create sprites for them. Just don't want to waste my time if there is something ready and usable already.

Answer (score 2):

[SpriteMe](http://spriteme.org/) is probably closest to what you're describing.

You might also want to look at [SmartSprites](http://csssprites.org/), which takes a different approach, more along the lines of CSS preprocessors like Sass, so it's actually integrated into your development rather than being done after the fact.