# Create sprites automatically

Tags: css, sprite

I get the folder with the following structure from my designer*:

> file.css
>
> images/

Is there any tool which can automatically create sprite from images folder and replace all images references from file.css to appropriate sprite section?

*It is actually not a designer (the man who creates design in, for example, Photoshop) but the man who makes html+css from it. How is this profession correctly called in English?

Comment: Designer is still the correct term.

Comment: @Peter Taylor, in russian language we separate them into "дизайнер" (designer) and "верстальщик" (I would verbatim translate it as "markuper"). I am pretty sure there is the same separation in English

Comment: @Idsa a lot of the time the person who does the design makes the basic html markup of the site (at least in my experience).  Anything complex will then be handed off to a "programmer".

Comment: Front-end developer. http://onlinetools.org/articles/fed2.html

Comment: You can have a 'designer' that literally just does the graphic design (in which case they are really a 'graphic designer') and a 'front end developer' that turns the design into HTML+CSS. But, depending on the company, these roles can merge.

Comment: Cross reference http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15548/automated-image-css-sprite-generation-from-website-dom

Answer (score 1):

There are various CSS sprite generators available online, including:

- [Spritegen](https://spritegen.website-performance.org/)
- [SmartSprites](https://www.csssprites.org/)
- [CSS Sprites](https://css-sprit.es/)
- [Web Sprite Generator](https://web.archive.org/web/20140130031655/http://westhoffswelt.de:80/projects/web-sprite-generator.html)

From my experience, the only way to generate CSS sprites while keeping file sizes down and maintaining control over compression is to do it manually.